# How to make web crawler for all e-commerce websites

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am new to scrapy. I would like to make my web crawler for my personal experiment,that would crawl the entire Internet and store the URL of e-commerce websites to my db.I have searched all over the Google ,and found this [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-crawl-a-web-page-with-scrapy-and-python-3) and many more are almost same.

But there is `start_urls = ['http://brickset.com/sets/year-2016']`
that I want to modify and want to add whole Internet.Is this possible ? if yes ,please guide me the right approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, this is not possible

Comment: Even Google themselves don't scan the whole internet. That's not possible.

Comment: So ,I have to provide the URLs to crawl every time ?

Answer (score 1):

So let's approach this problem a bit differently. It is actually impossible to build a crawler that can actually crawl all e-commerce websites and bring you the results.

This leaves us with our best option `Search Engines`. What you can rather do is crawl any of the search engines with your `product query` and gather links that have a product listed for selling.

The second challenge that you'll face is how to tell the difference between `e-commerce` sites and `other` sites. Tools like `DiffBot` would really help in that.

This needs to be done real-time cause obviously you won't be planning on making a humongous database of all the products out there on the indexed sites on internet.

Comment: That really helps me for the urgent solution ,but I have 1 more question. If this is not possible,Can you please tell the algorithm of google ,how can they crawl the pages ,I mean how can,they come to know , new website added , and have to crawl

Comment: Firstly, I guess this needs to be said, Google doesn't crawl cent percent of the web out there. Now, Google crawlers actually detect new links on web pages they've already crawled and put dead links, new links to a `to-be-crawled` queue. More info [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/70897?hl=en)

Comment: also, if my answer helps, please accept it as correct :)